# Undo delete list on saves leads to 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, saves, undo

Undo delete list [on saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current) leads to 404 page, needs to manually refresh the page:

> [image: Undo delete list]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a timing issue between our ReadOnly DB and our main DB. This should now be fixed for this endpoint! Please let us know if you find any other issues.

Thank you for reporting! We appreciate the help.