# Undo "delete Saves list" leads to page showing "0 saved items" in list when there are still items in the Saves list

Tags: bug, saves, undo

In a similar way to the following bug report: [Undo delete list on saves leads to 404 page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387169/1242908), undoing a delete of a Saves list displays the "0 saved items" page, however the items are still in the Saves list which can be shown by refreshing the page. To reproduce:

1. Create a Saves list and add some posts to it (with or without private notes)
2. Then delete the Saves list
3. Then undo the delete of the Saves list

[image: delete and undo a delete of a Saves list]

Undoing the delete of the Saves list results in the following display:

[image: 0 saved items page]

This gives the impression that **only** the Saves list has been undeleted, because the items in the Saves list are not visible.

However, refreshing the page displays the Saves list again and, in fact, nothing was deleted and the items reappear again (including any private notes attached to the Saves list).